# Installing Windows natively on MacBook Air without USB drive

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp

I have a late 2010 MacBook Air. I need to install Windows 7 natively (like BootCamp), but I don't have a USB drive.

What are my options?

**Update:** I mean USB Flash Drive.

Comment: USB flash drive

Comment: @ekaj Sorry I forgot that it's a MacBook Air. They don't have CD drives.

Comment: I think an 8g flash drive is like 10 bucks now.

Comment: money isn't the issue, I can't leave my home right now and I need to install it by tonight :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [RemoteDiskSharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1777?viewlocale=en_US) to access the drive on another computer (even a PC).

Comment: don't have access to another computer :(

Comment: Target Disk Mode would probably be easier.. But, he doesn't have access to another computer..

Answer (score 0):

You dont have acces to another computer, you can't leave getting an USB drive, and you dont have an external DVD-Drive, as far as I know, the only thing you can do is to download Parallels.

You can use it for free for 14 days, so you can use it until you get your hands on a thumb drive.

Parallels is quite power and performance consuming, seeing as it runs Windows inside OSX, but I dont know why you need to use Windows, or how important it is.

Link: https://nct.parallels.com/fulfill/0285.011

Comment: Also you can use Virtualbox (http://virtualbox.org), which is free for life and runs windows reasonably well (even with 3d acceleration in some older games if you are lucky)